# Playing sound when GUI is open

Tags: windows, forms, powershell

I am trying to play sound as long as the GUI is open, but as I am not familiar with powershell I need help..

Right now I have this:

```
$sound = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$sound.SoundLocation="c:\WINDOWS\Media\ringout.wav"
$Form.ShowDialog()
$sound.PlayLooping()
$flag=$false

1..10 | foreach {
    if ($_ -gt 5) {
         $flag=$true
    }
    else {
        sleep -s 1
    }
    if($flag) {
        $sound.Stop()
    }
}
```

Of course it's playing after I close this GUI, If I will put `$Form.ShowDialog()` at the end it will be play before GUI will show...
GUI is closed by button, simple `$Form.Close()`

**Edit ($Form declaration) :**

```
 $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
 $Form.Text = "ALERT"
 $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
 $Form.Topmost = $True
 $Form.BackColor = "White"
 $Form.AutoSize = $True
 $Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
 $Form.ControlBox = $false
```

I tried also with `if` and `while` loop but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: First, take a look at how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because at least `$Form` is not declared. Assuming it's a [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), do you heard about event handlers? `$Form.add_Closing({<#Stuff#>})`

Comment: @Clijsters I add $Form declaration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First things first. There is an important difference between `Form.Show()` and `$Form.ShowDialog()`. While `Show()` will return immediately, the latter one waits upon Dialog completion. So, if you start the music before `ShowDialog()` and stop it after that line, I don't know, why it shouldn't work.

---

For your needs, you might like [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/). Use the [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events(v=vs.110).aspx)s [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event to execute some logic while the form loads, and its [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event to add some logic when the form closes:

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    Text          = "ALERT"
    StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    Topmost       = $True
    BackColor     = "White"
    AutoSize      = $True
    AutoSizeMode  = "GrowAndShrink"
    ControlBox    = $false
}
$sound = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer -Property @{SoundLocation = "c:\WINDOWS\Media\ringout.wav"}

$Form.Add_Load({
    $sound.PlayLooping()
})

$Form.Add_Closing({
    $sound.Stop()
})

$Form.Show()
```

One might think for readability and reusability the following works better:

```
[scriptblock]$startMusic = {
    $sound.PlayLooping()
}

[scriptblock]$stopMusic = {
    $sound.Stop()
}

$Form.Add_Load($startMusic)
$Form.Add_Closing($stopMusic)
```

This would easily allow us to reuse those methods (e.g. for other dialogs and actions)

Comment: Nice! I really hope, you will not just copy&paste the (coincidentally working) code snippet and instead take look at the links provided to get a better understanding of this really helpful technologies.